# Python 3 shared libraries and pkg-config on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: apt, 20.04, python3, pkg-config

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and while the `pkg-config` query

```
pkg-config --cflags python3
```

returns sensible values for C compilation, the query

```
pkg-config --libs python3
```

returns nothing.

I think I have installed all conceivable `python3`/`python3.8` packages possible, including `libpython3` packages, but the result is always the same.

I am aware that one can get appropriate library flags by using the query:

```
pkg-config --libs python3-embed
```

but this breaks backward compatibility so it's an all but desirable workaround.

**The question is:** is there a way to make

```
pkg-config --libs python3
```

or

```
pkg-config --libs python3.8
```

return the appropriate libpython flags?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks that `python3 --libs` is not coming back.

This bug report: https://bugs.python.org/issue36721 suggests that `python3-embed` is now the way to go, as Python now distinguishes between extension and embedding in the build process.